# Why is my training loss very high when training tensorflow object detection ssd mobilenet model

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api, mobilenet

I am trying to create my own custom object detector using tensorflow api models ssd mobile net, but the problem is that when the model starts training the loss is very high like 700-800 and the loss keeps fluctuating, and I see same values of loss being repeated, can someone please explain this to me. I had initially trained the model for 7000 steps, but the loss didnt reduce then I had started training the model again. I am sharing the screenshot of my new training. I have been stuck on this for almost two days now, and would really appreciate any help.
I have 16482 images in my train dataset, and my image size is 64x64

[image: loss]

Comment: without providing any information about your data, model, etc we can only guess.
did you normalize your inputs? Is your model big enough to be able to fit the data? is there even a pattern that can be learned? ...

Comment: It seems your loss is oscillating. Try decreasing the learning rate. Else use this repo to set up the object - detection - model and try different model and see if the same thing happens - [Link](https://github.com/aniketbote/automatic-object-detection-setup)

Comment: @AniketBote hey, is this repo for custom object detection.

Comment: Yes. It automatically downloads everything and sets up the path, create tfrecords , model model, create config files and finally outputs the command for training as well as evaluation of the model.

Answer (score -1):

please check the image formats all images should be in same format(JPG or JPEG), remove PNG images.and try training

Answer (score -1):

If you are sure that your dataset is fine, then this issue probably has something to do with the learning rate of your model. If you're using the tensorflow object detector you can change this learning rate in the config file of the base transfer learning model